# Google Maps API - get water body name

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can i get Water body name from google map api?
For example, when i click on map i choose "What's here?" popup will appear with lake name and coordinates. I need that name. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lake Michigan is in the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/) at those coordinates.  The "name" is "Lake Michigan / Michigan City" however.

Using the Google Maps Javascript API v3 Places Library:

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var infowindow;
var service;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.4501005, -87.2220187),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: map.getCenter(),
    radius: 500
  }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    console.log("OK:" + results.length)
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      console.log(results[i]);
      var marker = createMarker(results[i]);
      if (i == 0) google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name + "<br>place_id:" + place.place_id);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
    service.getDetails({
      placeId: place.place_id
    }, function(place, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
            'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
            place.formatted_address + '</div>');
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
        google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
      }
    });
  });
  return marker;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, but what about other smaller lakes, for ex. Old Wives Lake (50.111392, -106.031389)? When i use script from above, it returns nothing.